# Are there UI guidelines for facebook canvas apps?

Tags: facebook, user-interface, canvas

Does Facebook offer guidelines or some kind of CSS style library for Facebook canvas apps? Something that a developer could use to make the look and feel of their canvas app compliment Facebook? I'm speaking along the lines of fonts, colors, dialog box styles, etc.

I guess, in theory, I'm looking for something along the lines of interface builder in iOS development.

Answer (score 1):

Understanding the [Platform Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) will help you better design and develop your app. Check the [examples and explanations](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/examples_and_explanations) too.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook has published a [social design guideline](https://developers.facebook.com/socialdesign/).  They also have a [brand permissions guideline](https://www.facebook.com/brandpermissions/) for when you want to use their logo, colors, etc.  But they don't have a specific css/stylesheet guideline like you are asking for.

Answer (score -1):

The following is a link to everything that facebook offers a developer, it does not include any stylesheet guidelines:

https://github.com/facebook

The only thing I could think of is when I was implementing Facebook credits, Facebook had guidelines regarding the image to use and a best practice for the flow of purchasing a virtual item with Facebook credits besides that you should be able to develop your app however you like.

You said you where looking for something along the lines of interface builder in iOS development, but I would compare facebook more like the interface builder for Android, everything goes.

Comment: the Facebook github account is **NOT** the place to look for guidelines! It's a place to check for example apps and official SDKs.

Comment: I didn't say it was the place guidelines.